# how to debug a production app in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I currently have a production app that is error-ing out on a page, it just says

```
The webpage is not available
```

When I download the code and run it on my local machine, it runs perfectly.

Just wondering how can I debug the production site? There is no source code on the production site, only the assemblies... can I turn the debug to true?

otherwise what are my other options?

Thanks

Comment: if you turn on  the debug you could get the yellow screen with the specific error

Comment: If you have logging - look at your logs, if you done nothing - look at event viewer on the production server to see detailed exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `customErrors` attribute's `mode` value to `RemoteOnly`. This will show the normal custom error message for external visitors but if you browse the page on the actual server it will display you a detailed .NET Yellow Screen of Death.

MSDN: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

..and yes, you may also want to set `debug="true"` in the web.config whilst you do this (but set it back afterward).

You can also check the event logs on the server for detailed exception messages which will give you a hint as to what the problem may be.

Answer (score 1):

Modify customErrors in your web.config.  If you have access to remote desktop to the server, set it to RemoteOnly.  If you don't, then set it to Off:

```
<system.web>
   <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

If you still see the custom error page, ensure the machine.config is not overriding the customErrors setting, and also ensure that the machine.config is not setting the deployment mode to retail=true.  In your machine.config, the deployment setting should look like this:

```
<deployment retail="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

`<compilation debug="true"> </compilation>`(in your Web.Config).Do turn it off while deploying it to Production.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting your app in Azure Web Sites its pretty simple. See my blog post  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/05/remote-debugging-a-window-azure-web-site-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx. As far as I know Azure Web Sites is the only multi-tenant hosting provider that offers remote debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging a production web site is something of an art form.  Typically there are a number of constraints that prevent you from doing what you would on a non-production site.  For example, it would be a very bad idea to attach a debugger to the process!!!

Here's a few points to get you started.

1. You ought to have a staging or pre-production web site.  Your first step should be to attempt to reproduce the problem there.  If you can reproduce it, great!  Debug it on the staging site instead.
2. There are a number of logs that are provided by the system that you can turn on.  Windows event logs will tell you if anything catastrophic has happened.  IIS logs will tell you if the web request is even reaching your application.  Fusion logs will tell you if any DLLs are missing or cannot be bound.  etc.
3. When looking at logs, remember that your production system may have more than one node.  It may be helpful to take all but one of your web nodes out of the load balancer so that you're sure to generate logs on a given box.
4. Hopefully the application was written with some kind of logging of its own (e.g. using log4net).  Audit trails and debug logs should help you identify the problem.
5. Use a stopwatch.  If it takes exactly 30 or 60 seconds for the error to occur, it is likely there is some connection in your system that is timing out.  The client and server endpoints of your applications' internal connections (e.g. database connections or web services) will have logs of their own, too.  More stuff to look at!

Your emphasis should be on identifying the specific component and/or class that is having an issue.  Once you have narrowed it down sufficiently, you may have to visually "step through" your code to detect any kind of logic errors.  Write down all the input variables, open up source control, and ask yourself line by line what the code would do given all the the inputs.

It can be very difficult to debug a production web site.  Good luck!